# Error The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel. only on Windows Server 2012

Tags: c#, ssl, windows-server-2012

I know there are few similar questions about this error, but my question is a little bit different because my code works on local, actually from Windows 10, and when I deploy it on production environment (Windows Server 2012) it does not work.

So this is the story. I try to contact service and I'm getting an error:

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

This error started to happen few days ago and we got an email from that service which tells they no longer support some ciphers. This is their email:

> This means that from December, 1st we will only support the following cipher suites:

```
Cipher suites (TLS 1.3):
TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256

Cipher suites (TLS 1.2):
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
CDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305
ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305
DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
```

I found few solutions that suggest to include all TLS protocols, which I've already done. This is part of my code:

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls 
   | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 
   | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 
   | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

But the problem is the same. So call to service works on my local but does not work on Windows Server.

I also compered cipher suites in Registry (location HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Cryptography\Configuration\Local\SSL\00010003)
and I've seen there is a difference between my Windows 10 and Windows Service.
So what I tried is to manually copy all ciphers from my computer to windows server, but still I'm getting the same error.

So I don't have idea anymore what could be the problem. Please help!

p.s. I forgot to mention that I tried many different solutions, like including only TLS1.2 protocol. This is a part of code that also did not work:

```
 ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
 ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Comment: SSL and TLS 1.0 and 1.1 where disabled by a Microsoft security patch from June This year..  So change to ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;. The certificate must be compatible with the TLS version. See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security.  Make sure the Server has all the security patches so it can run with TLS 1.2.

Comment: I didn't mention that I tried 10 different solutions. I also tried solution you suggest, but it also didn't work. This is a part of commented code which I also tried, that is the solution you suggest: 
                    //ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
                    //ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Comment: You probably need to use a sniffer and verify that TLS 1.2 is being used.  There is a TLS Certificate block that gets return from the server with a list of certificate names that can be used.  The client compares the names with the ones stored in the user account.  So a certificate has to match a certificate with the correct encryption mode.  Then the certificate is text so the encryption mode must match the list above.  It is possible the server is returning a certificate name with the an unacceptable encryption mode.  You also may need to add TLS 1.3 as a possible mode.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. This is an older project, .NET framework 4.6.1, so unfortunately I can't include TLS13. Anyway, I suspect that's not a problem, because I really tried all possible combinations with protocols :). I suspect it has something to do  with ciphers...

Comment: Either you do not have installed a certificate for TLS 1.2 (the encryption modes that are acceptable) or it is taking an older certificate.  You need to use a sniffer to look at the certificate names to determine if you have the right certificate installed.  An you have to look at the XML file (text) to see the encryption mode in the certificate.

Answer (score -1):

That should be Cipher Suites problem.

There are some Cipher Suites that not available on the previous version of Windows.

Scan your application with ssllabs or Wireshark to know the problems.
Enable supported Cipher Suites that disabled on the destination server.

- [Fix: SSL Handshaking Error in Windows Server 2008 R2 / 2012 R2](https://blog.jonschneider.com/2016/08/fix-ssl-handshaking-error-in-windows.html)
- [Cipher Suites in TLS/SSL (Schannel SSP)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/cipher-suites-in-schannel)
- [SSL Server Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html)